# How to solve for angle between two lines or vectors without a calculator?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I know how to solve for the angle between two lines, but I don't know how to do it without a calculator because of arctan. I know it is possible for angles such as 0,30,45,60..., but is it possible for any two random lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any two random vectors, you can get$$\vec x \cdot \vec y =\Vert x \Vert \Vert y \Vert \cos <\vec x, \vec y>$$

And that is all. You can only get the cosine of the angle, but no more.

It is not possible (read: practical) to manually perform $\arccos$ on a random cosine value (e. g. $0.7$)

Comment: If you really care, yes use Taylor expansion you *can*, and that is what the calculator is doing behind the scenes, but it's simply impractical

Comment: Yeah I should have added that this was going to be used on a precalculus math competition that didn't allow calculators. The Taylor series might be good for approximating the first view values

Comment: @aarush warning the Taylor expansion of $\arccos$ is incredibly complex, and even its second order derivative seems to be too terrible to be practical; it is generally better to just draw the two vectors and appeal to your protractor

Answer (score 2):

The inverse trigonometric functions all output an angle.  For example, it would be perfectly fine to say that the angle between $l_1$ and $l_2$ is $\arccos\left(\frac3{16}\right)$.

Comment: Ok, that was what bothered me.

Answer (score 1):

For random angles, you would have to resort to Taylor series expansion around any known or derivable value but it would be too tedious and not worth the time and it is best left to calculator.